# Install libssl1.0.0 on ubuntu 10.04 offline quickly

Tags: package, ubuntu-10.04, libssl

I need to install libssl1.0.0 on a ubuntu 10.04 machine offline.

After lots of search, I still cannot find any libssl1.0.0 packages built for ubuntu 10.04. Building it from source is not accepted, because it takes several minutes to complete the build and installation process while I only have few seconds to finish the job.

Please advise me how to quickly install libssl1.0.0 on ubuntu 10.04 offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I use `checkinstall` to build debian package from last version of source. If `checkinstall` does not exist in the system, it can be installed by `apt-get install checkinstall`. The rest of steps are:

```
tar xf openssl-1.0.1e.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.1e
./config --prefix=/usr shared
make
checkinstall
```

Then `openssl_1.0.1e-1_amd64.deb` will be available under `openssl-1.0.1e` folder.